# how to start and stop sensor android

Tags: android

I am working on the sensor action in iphone and I was wondering if anyone would know how to implement the start and stop sensor actions in android. I have searched this forum but not been able to find something definitive. Does anyone have and clues?Maybe an example I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android `Sensor Manager` for using sensor action.

here is one example of sensor..

[click here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (exemple for the proximity sensor. Yo can implement this on a onclick of a button.

```
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this,sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY));
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved issue by this code:

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY));
```